# Python: For loop problem

Tags: html, for-loop, python-server-pages

I have a PSP page with html embedded. I need to place another for loop so i can insert another %s next to `background-color:` which will instert a appropriate colour to colour in the html table.

For example i need to insert `for z in colours` so it can loop over the colours list and insert the correct colour. Where ever i try to insert the for loop it doesnt seem to work it most commonly colours each cell in the table 60 times then moves onto the next cell and repeats itself and crashes my web browser.

The colours are held in a table called colours.

code below:

```
<table>
<%
s = ''.join(aa[i] for i in table if i in aa)
for i in range(0, len(s), 60):
    req.write('<tr><td><TT>%04d</td>' % (i+1));
    for k in s[i:i+60]:
            req.write('<TT><td><TT><font style="background-color:">%s<font></td>' % (k));
    req.write('</TT></tr>')
#end
%>
</table>
```

**-----EDITED-----**

Plugged in the code provided ebo, it colours the table all one colour. The colours list contains a variety of colours e.g. `colour = ['yellow', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red']`

```
<table>
<%
s = ''.join(aa[i] for i in table if i in aa)
for i in range(0, len(s), 60):
    req.write('<tr><td>%04d</td>' % (i+1));
    for j, k in enumerate(s[i:i+60]):
        req.write('<td><font style="background-color:%s;">%s<font></td>' % (colour[j % len(colour)], k));
    req.write('</tr>')
#end
%>
</table>
```

Comment: By the way, you are producing really bad HTML code. :-(

Comment: I know i just want a working page at the moment...

Comment: A working page will include valid html code. Please fix your html first and add an example for colours.

Comment: What is the intermediate `for k` doing? Which number is meant to be an index into the colours table? Is it just `i`? In that case it should be `colours[i % len(colours)]`.

Comment: But what's `s`? What does it have to do with `colours`? Can you be more precise about the ordering of the sequence you want to get out?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want one color for each column. Best idea would be to use enumerate:

```
s = ''.join(aa[i] for i in table if i in aa)
for i in range(0, len(s), 60):
    req.write('<tr><td>%04d</td>' % (i+1))
    for j, k in enumerate(s[i:i+60]):
        req.write('<td style="background-color: %s;">%s</td>' % 
                     (colours[j % len(colours)], k))
    req.write('</tr>')
```

I stripped all the `TT` tags. They were mostly wrong, either not closed or spanning over other elements.

**Update** This should do. Take a look at the source, if every field is filled correctly. Also download [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/1843) and take a look at the parsed html code. It may differ depending on your other html failures.

```
colour = ["red", "red", "green", "yellow"]

print "<table>"
s = '1234567890'
for i in range(0, len(s), 60):
    print('<tr><td>%04d</td>' % (i+1));
    for j, k in enumerate(s[i:i+60]):
        print('<td><font style="background-color:%s;">%s<font></td>' % (colour[j % len(colour)], k));
    print('</tr>')
print "</table>"
```

I piped the output of the following code into a html file and opened it. Works as expected.

```
python table.py > table.html
firefox table.html
```

I guess you have some additional errors in your code which mess up parsing.

Comment: Hey plugged your code in, the table came up as all one colour. The colour list contains a list of colours e.g. ['yellow', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'green', 'green']